# div tag get automatically wrapped into <a> tag?

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="tagline">
<h1>Around The World In 80 Clicks</h1>
</div>
```

Above is a code snippet from my HTML code. Problem is `<a>` tag is auto-generated around "tagline" div and consequently `<h1>` is converted into a link.

I am using CSS too but no style is applied on `<div id="tagline">`.

Why is it generated by itself? How can I remove it?

Comment: Nothing in that code will cause a link to be generated

Comment: There must be a `<a />` no closing tag or attributes `"` double quote missing above `#tagline` element which cause it.

Comment: What is making you think that `h1` is converted into a link?!

Comment: thnx...i was missing a closing </a> tag. :)

Answer (score 1):

You must have missed a closing anchor tag `</a>` somewhere above the code that you have posted.

```
<a>......</a>
<div id="tagline">
<h1>Around The World In 80 Clicks</h1>
</div>
```

This must solve the problem !

Or

You may have mistaken the property `cursor:pointer` to a link ! Check this out too. not sure though!

Answer (score 0):

Try using these validators. Maybe you committed typo errors.

For HTML.
http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_upload

For CSS.
http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_upload

Answer (score 0):

Is there link higher up in your code? If so then close it off with This:

```
<a></a>
```